# JSON Data - Nested tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my JSON data :

```
{
    "main_menu": [
        {
            "main_menu_id": "1212",
            "main_submenu": [
                {
                    "main_submenu_info": {
                        "main_count":2
                    },
                    "one" : "A",
                    "two" : "B"  
                },
                {
                  "one" : "A",
                  "two" : "B"
                }
            ],
            "main_r": 0.1
        }
    ],
    "main_count": 1
}
```

How do i reach the main_count : 2 data in the  main submenu using jquery once i recieve this data ?

Comment: That's basic access to object properties. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FWorking_with_Objects)

Comment: Each array entry must be indexed, the others are simple key/value pairs where you can use chaining: `var mainCount = YOURJSONOBJECT.main_menu[0].main_submenu[0].main_submenu_info.main_count`

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with it. jQuery is just a plugin developed using javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var data = {
    "main_menu": [
        {
            "main_menu_id": "1212",
            "main_submenu": [
                {
                    "main_submenu_info": {
                        "main_count":2
                    },
                    "one" : "A",
                    "two" : "B"  
                },
                {
                  "one" : "A",
                  "two" : "B"
                }
            ],
            "main_r": 0.1
        }
    ],
    "main_count": 1
};

alert(data.main_menu[0].main_submenu[0].main_submenu_info.main_count);
```

Or via an ajax request in Jquery:

```
$.post(url, function(data){
   alert(data.main_menu[0].main_submenu[0].main_submenu_info.main_count);
});
```

Read up on JSON and property access [here](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Comment: @Bojangles That is debatable, for all we know this could be the individuals first experience with JSON, not everyone can be an expert or knows where to find the relevant information.

Comment: @Bojangles I wind up saying this a lot, but the question has a code example and a clear goal, which makes it better than 50% of the questions asked on SO.

Comment: True, but it makes me cringe when I see an answer to an RTFM question that just posts the solution with no explanation. That said, you've edited in a link now so that's solved

Comment: @KevinBowersox : I had earlier tried the same thing as you have mentioned above , but the problem being that the console shows up an error saying that : cannot read property "main_count" of undefined ?

Comment: @stark Are you sure you accessed the arrays using the subscript operators `[0]`?  Here is the fiddle I used to make this example: http://jsfiddle.net/VUjqt/  Also are you talking about the jquery example or `var data =`?

Comment: @KevinBowersox : hey yeah it worked , also another problem i am facing is since in the above case i dont use the $.each function to traverse through multiple main menus but in that case , when i can't use [0] rather i would have to use a [index] variable , then this doesn;t seem to work in such a case ?